# Breaking equations under parentheses in nested environments of LyX

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I want to reproduce something like this in LyX: [image: Multi line Equation]

Any suggestions as to how I can achieve line-breaking as depicted in the picture (in the rather long definition of a particular set under item (b), to be precise)?

Which (AMS?) environment should I use? All my trials so far seem to end with misaligned and indented results.

What I want is this: the second line under (b) should start from the left just as in the picture.

P. S.: I'd prefer a solution, if any, without using the breqn package.

Comment: Thanks, @rico for fixing the pic; was my first time using the Android app. :P

Comment: Why not use inline math? That's what's used in the picture.

Comment: @torbjørn: you mean inline mode under an enumerate environment with manually specified bracket sizes?

Comment: Yes, sounds about right.

Comment: Well, `\bigl` and `\bigr` under enumerate seem to be working fine inasmuch as the sizes of the curly brackets are concerned; thanks, @torbjørn. LyX can't handle it on its own without us having to resort to inputting direct LaTeX code, though.

Comment: Yes it can, there's an *Insert delimiters* button on the math toolbar. That said, do you even need bigger delimiters?

Comment: We'd actually used the toolbar buttons ourselves, but the principle remains the same. Delimiters of bigger sizes were indeed required as the other types of braces used in the formula were auto-sized by LyX.